# What do you call the use of a negative clause to end a claim by questioning it?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I mean the clause at the end, seemingly asking for confirmation of the claim.

> You would like to sleep, wouldn't you?

What is this called?

Comment: See these related questions: [“tag question” vs. “question tag”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30713/tag-question-vs-question-tag); [About question tags](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2367/about-question-tags)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thanks, didn't know that; I've been doing that mistake for ages!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construction is called a [tag question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question) (or question tag), with the *tag* being the question part at the end.

Comment: Of course, the negative can go in either the tag, as here, **or** in the original statement, in which case the tag is affirmative: _You wouldn't like to sleep, would you?_ One or the other must be negative, and the tag **must** be contracted, if it's negative.

Comment: @JohnLawler Oh, they must, must they? (I'm not trying to be confrontational, of course. It just seemed like an appropriate demonstration that although what you said is true in most cases, the statement or the tag need not be negative if the intent is ironic or argumentative.)

Comment: That's not a tag question. Tag questions aren't threatening; if anything, they're deferential. That's, as you put it, a confrontational tag, not at all the same construction. Note that it requires **both** parts to be affirmative; if they're both negative, it's ungrammatical -- _*You don't want to leave, don't you?_

Comment: @JohnLawler Interesting, I didn't know there was a distinction.  I guess it makes sense given the different intents and constructions, as you pointed out. Thanks for teaching me something new!