# Ending a sentence with "has it" or "did it" in a sarcastic statement, what's this called?

Tags: questions, rhetorical-devices, question-tags

E.g. 1:

"Oh, that joke about a pandemic has aged like fine wine, hasn't it?"

E.g. 2:

"Yes, I suppose we did, didn't we?"

I've noticed alot of people from the UK tend to speak in a manner like this, so I'm supposing there's a name for it, and rules for its usage along with many other interesting examples of said usage ... and so on, and so on. You know, like Brits tend to do.

I would say it's just a rhetorical statement/question/device (thing), but I haven't seen any other examples of sentences like this poking around the web.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: All native speakers use tags. Both in question form and negative interrogative form with all the auxiliary verbs and the verb to be. If you want to become more fluent, you might try this, which will get you started: https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/question-tags-exercise-1.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call the use of a negative clause to end a claim by questioning it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68403/what-do-you-call-the-use-of-a-negative-clause-to-end-a-claim-by-questioning-it)

Comment: It has zero to do with sarcasm per se. If you want to speak English well, you should work on your tags, shouldn't you? It has zero to do with BrE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a "question tag" or "tag question":

> **tag question**
>   A question used after a statement when seeking or expecting confirmation of that statement, as *wasn't he* in *He was here, wasn't he?*
>   [TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/question+tag)

More from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question):

> A question tag (also known as question tail) is a grammatical structure in which a declarative or an imperative statement is turned into a question by the addition of an interrogative fragment (the "tag"). For example, in the sentence "You're John, aren't you?", the statement "You're John" is turned into a question by the tag "aren't you".[1]

There is no special air of sarcasm that attaches to a question tag. It's really all in the delivery. Normal usage is just to solicit agreement or further information.

See also: [Punctuating question tags: A question mark is always required, isn't it. (Well, isn't it?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71193/punctuating-question-tags-a-question-mark-is-always-required-isnt-it-well)