# Comma at the end of a sentence?

Tags: commas, sentence-ends

Is it correct to use a comma before the word "correct" in the following sentences: You get in tonight, correct? Or her name is Mary, correct?

If so, what's the rule for this?

Comment: I doesn't make sense without the comma - say it out loud without a pause and you'll see. The comma (simplistically) denotes a pause when speaking, and this is shown in print as a comma.

Comment: I've not seen an 'authoritative ruling' on this one. This usage is as a _sentence substitute_, (for 'Is that correct?') – which term Collins defines thus: **n**  1. (Linguistics) a word or phrase, esp one traditionally classified as an adverb, that is used in place of a finite sentence, such as _yes_, _no_, _certainly_, and _never_ Collins English Dictionary >> So the grammar police could argue that it needs at least a semicolon or dash, if not a full stop and capitalisation. I'm happy with the comma, but that's a minimum requirement.

Comment: Highly related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30713/tag-question-vs-question-tag

Answer (score 2):

It is a phrase that attaches itself at the end of a regular sentence:

> "Her name is Mary." + "right?"

The main sentence is complete in all respects.

The phrase that comes in is "attached" **using a comma**.

> "Her name is Mary, right?"

"right?" here is known as a 'question tag.' Notice that this is always an interrogative (question).

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question)

> A **question tag** or **tag question** is a grammatical structure in which a declarative statement or an imperative is turned into a question by adding an interrogative fragment (the "tag"). For example, in the sentence "You're John, aren't you?", the statement "You're John" is turned into a question by the tag "aren't you". The term "question tag" is generally preferred by British grammarians, while their American counterparts prefer "tag question".